# How to get physical disk number by drive letter using Delphi

Tags: delphi, hardware, disk

Sorry, I know NOTHING about this subject, so asking for your help. I found this code below on Google, to get physical disk number by drive letter, and despite it works, takes about 4 or 5 seconds to get the result. I'd like to know if there is a faster way and how to do it? Thanks!

```
function GetPhysicalDiskNumber(Drive: Char): Byte;

  function GetLD(Drive: Char): Cardinal;
  var
    Buffer : String;
  begin
    Buffer := Format('\\.\%s:',[Drive]);
    Result := CreateFile(PChar(Buffer),GENERIC_READ Or GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ,nil,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);
    If Result = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then
      begin
      Result := CreateFile(PChar(Buffer),GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,nil,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);
    end;
  end;

type
  PDiskInfo = ^TDiskInfo;
  TDiskInfo = record
    BootStatus,
    StartHead    : Byte;
    StartSecClu  : Array[0..1]  Of Byte;
    ParitionType,
    LastHead     : Byte;
    LastSecClu   : Array[0..1]  Of Byte;
    ABSSector,
    TTLSector    : Integer;
    Reserved     : Array[0..47] Of Byte;
    Signature    : Array[0..1]  Of Byte;
  end;
  TDiskExtent = record
    DiskNumber: Cardinal;
    StartingOffset: Int64;
    ExtentLength: Int64;
  end;
  DISK_EXTENT = TDiskExtent;
  PDiskExtent = ^TDiskExtent;
  TVolumeDiskExtents = record
    NumberOfDiskExtents: Cardinal;
    Extents: array[0..0] of TDiskExtent;
  end;
  VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS = TVolumeDiskExtents;
  PVolumeDiskExtents = ^TVolumeDiskExtents;

const
  FILE_DEVICE_DISK                     = $00000007;
  METHOD_BUFFERED                      = 0;
  FILE_ANY_ACCESS                      = 0;
  IOCTL_DISK_BASE                      = FILE_DEVICE_DISK;
  IOCTL_VOLUME_BASE                    = DWORD('V');
  IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS = ((IOCTL_VOLUME_BASE shl 16) or (FILE_ANY_ACCESS shl 14) or (0 shl 2) or METHOD_BUFFERED);

var
  LD : DWORD;
  DiskExtents : PVolumeDiskExtents;
  DiskExtent : TDiskExtent;
  BytesReturned : Cardinal;
begin
  Result := 0;
  LD := GetLD(Drive);
  If LD = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then Exit;
  Try
    DiskExtents := AllocMem(Max_Path);
    DeviceIOControl(LD,IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS,nil,0,DiskExtents,Max_Path,BytesReturned,nil);
    If DiskExtents^.NumberOfDiskExtents > 0 Then
      begin
      DiskExtent := DiskExtents^.Extents[0];
      Result := DiskExtent.DiskNumber;
    end;
  Finally
    CloseHandle(LD);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Try `FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE`

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Passed in where? CreateFile? Both or just one or the other?

Comment: Thank you @SertacAkyuz for your comment, but I have no idea how to try your tip. Please, can you add more information?

Comment: @Jerry - Two calls are one too much already, remove the first one - no need for write access. Should raise an exception when it fails also.. I don't believe the code is working as it is now - not for the system volume at least.. The delay is probably the timeout for the system trying to lock the volume against write access.

Comment: @Astral - Also try showing some effort - reading the code you use would be a good start. You will recognize where you can try what I suggested.

Comment: Continuing wat Sertac said, if you're not too familiar with Delphi syntax, a big hint is the actual procedure starts towards the end of your code, with `Result := 0;`, then it calls `GetLD` (which is defined near the top). Might be easier for you to understand if you extract the function `GetLD`, the types, and the constants out and place them above the procedure definition. It can be confusing when all that's nested inside the function.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, you mean on the GetLD function, to remove the first Result and leave only the second like "CreateFile(PChar(Buffer), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);" ?

Comment: @JerryDodge, I am familiar with Delphi syntax, but I am not familiar with this kind of code, to handle hardware.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, it is working faster now, after your tip! But do you think I can not have problems removing the first "Result" on the GetLD function?

Comment: @Astral - Read my comment to Jerry.

Comment: function GetLD(Drive: Char): Cardinal;
  var
    Buffer : String;
  begin
    Buffer := Format('\\.\%s:', [Drive]);
    Result := CreateFile(PChar(Buffer), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
  end;

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, this is what I understood from your comments... Sorry, english is not my native language...

Comment: "100% faster" technically does not make any sense. Literally speaking, that means the exact same speed as before. However that information shouldn't be a part of your question, but rather an answer. Why Sertac didn't put it in the form of answer is beyond me.

Comment: @Jerry "100% faster" means always "double performance" or going from 100mph to 200mph or 1 information in 4 seconds to 1 information in 2 seconds ...

Comment: OMG, you guys need therapy... I just subscribed here, trying to do my best... And what happens if no one answers? I just wanted to leave the correct "answer" for those who came for it...

Comment: @Astral - Does it take 2 - 2.5 seconds now, or is it immediate?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, the result is now immediate! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Documentation for `CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx#physical_disks_and_volumes) states:

> • When opening a volume or floppy disk, the dwShareMode parameter must have the **FILE_SHARE_WRITE** flag.

The code you're using is missing the flag. The code also has a peculiar characteristic in that it does not notify failure. When `CreateFile` fails, your `GetPhysicalDiskNumber` returns '0', suggesting the result is the first disk.

This is what I think is happening: you're testing on a volume that the system cannot lock against write access and times out while trying to do so (hence the delay). But your function still returns '0', so you think it is working.

In any case, you need the flag. I would, additionally, raise an exception when `CreateFile` fails, so that you'd have a clue what is happening.

```
  function GetLD(Drive: Char): Cardinal;
  var
    Buffer : String;
  begin
    Buffer := Format('\\.\%s:',[Drive]);
    Result := CreateFile(PChar(Buffer), GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
    Win32Check(Result <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
  end;
```

You may choose to have a silent fail though. In that case you can initially set `Result` of `GetPhysicalDiskNumber` to '-1' for instance, and pass on raising an exception for `CreateFile` and `DeviceIoControl`.

The code also fails to release the memory it allocates, that's a leak:

```
  ...
  try
    DiskExtents := AllocMem(Max_Path);
    try
      Win32Check(DeviceIOControl(LD, IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS, nil, 0,
          DiskExtents, Max_Path, BytesReturned, nil));
      if DiskExtents^.NumberOfDiskExtents > 0 then
      begin
        DiskExtent := DiskExtents^.Extents[0];
        Result := DiskExtent.DiskNumber;
      end;
    finally
      FreeMem(DiskExtents);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(LD);
  ...
```

Comment: It is possible to find all the drive letters knowing the physical disk number ?

Comment: @Marus - You might want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33615577/how-to-enumerate-the-volumes-on-a-phyiscal-drive-using-windows-api).