# How to enumerate the volumes on a phyiscal drive using Windows API?

Tags: winapi, hardware, enumeration

I'm trying to create a list of partitions and their volumes of all the (fixed) disks in the system (Something like: PhyiscalDrive0, Partition 1, C:\; PhyiscalDrive0, Partition 2, D:\; ...) . I already got the list of installed disks via SetupApi and IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER, as well as the number of partition.

The problem I'm having is how to find out the drive letters that are mounted to a partiticular partition (in meaning of partition 1 of Physical drive is C:\, for example)?

Thanks in before for any help,

Willi K.

Comment: A mounted volume does not necessarily have a drive letter. Partitions can stretch across multiple drives, too.

Answer (score 2):

The API you probably want to use is the [Storage Management API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh830613(v=vs.85).aspx).   This provides a way to query just about anything you want.   In particular, the drive letters are part of the [MSFT_Volume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh830604(v=vs.85).aspx) class.   The API isn't the friendliest for C++, which is why I'm not providing a sample query, but there's a [sample here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Storage-management-ddef6afc/sourcecode?fileId=51175&pathId=1939749066) that shows how to write queries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Eric Brown. I gave you a vote for the answer - however I have to admit that I currently choosed the other way (enumerate the volumes and use IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER which tells me drive number and partiion number).
I will come back to this when it becomes absolutely esssential the go the other way.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have obtained the drives through the setup api you need to obtain information about partitions (through IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX) and especially their starting offset and length.
Here is the code I use inside my library libwindevblk ([libwindevblk](https://github.com/vricosti/libwindevblk/blob/master/README.md)):

```
BOOL FindVolume(int diskno, PSMI_DEVBLK_ENTRY pDevBlkEntry) 
{
HANDLE vol;
BOOL success;
TCHAR szNextVolName[MAX_PATH+1];
TCHAR szNextVolNameNoBSlash[MAX_PATH+1];

vol = FindFirstVolume(szNextVolName, MAX_PATH);
success = (vol != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
while (success)
{
    //We are now enumerating volumes. In order for this function to work, we need to get partitions that compose this volume
    HANDLE volH;
    PVOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS vde;
    DWORD bret;

    //For this CreateFile, volume must be without trailing backslash
    StringCchCopy(szNextVolNameNoBSlash, MAX_PATH, szNextVolName);
    szNextVolNameNoBSlash[_tcslen(szNextVolNameNoBSlash) - 1] = _T('\0'); 

    volH = CreateFile(szNextVolNameNoBSlash,
        FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES | SYNCHRONIZE | FILE_TRAVERSE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    if (volH != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        bret = sizeof(VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS) + 256 * sizeof(DISK_EXTENT);
        vde = (PVOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS)malloc(bret);
        if (DeviceIoControl(volH, IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS, NULL, 0, (void *)vde, bret, &bret, NULL))
        {
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < vde->NumberOfDiskExtents; i++)
            {
                if (vde->Extents[i].DiskNumber == diskno &&
                    vde->Extents[i].StartingOffset.QuadPart == pDevBlkEntry->StartingOffset.QuadPart &&
                    vde->Extents[i].ExtentLength.QuadPart == pDevBlkEntry->PartitionLength.QuadPart)
                {
                    CHAR szVolumeName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
                    CHAR szFileSystemName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
                    DWORD dwSerialNumber = 0;
                    DWORD dwMaxFileNameLength = 0;
                    DWORD dwFileSystemFlags = 0;

                    if (GetVolumeInformation(szNextVolName,
                        szVolumeName, _countof(szVolumeName),
                        &dwSerialNumber,
                        &dwMaxFileNameLength,
                        &dwFileSystemFlags,
                        szFileSystemName,
                        _countof(szFileSystemName)))
                    {
                        _tcsncpy(pDevBlkEntry->szRootPathName, szNextVolName, MAX_PATH);
                        _tcsncpy(pDevBlkEntry->szVolumeName, szVolumeName, MAX_PATH);
                        _tcsncpy(pDevBlkEntry->szFileSystemName, szFileSystemName, MAX_PATH);
                        pDevBlkEntry->dwSerialNumber = dwSerialNumber;
                        pDevBlkEntry->dwFileSystemFlags = dwFileSystemFlags;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
                        printf("%lu", dwErr);
                    }

                    DWORD length = 0;
                    TCHAR pathnames[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
                    if (GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeName(szNextVolName, (LPTSTR)pathnames, MAX_PATH, &length))
                    {
                        _tcsncpy(pDevBlkEntry->szVolumePathName, pathnames, MAX_PATH);
                    }

                    free(vde);
                    CloseHandle(volH);
                    FindVolumeClose(vol);
                    return TRUE;
                } 
            }//for
        }
        free(vde);
        CloseHandle(volH);
    }

    success = FindNextVolume(vol, szNextVolName, MAX_PATH) != 0;
}
FindVolumeClose(vol);
return FALSE;
```

}

Comment: For some volumes CreateFile fails with "access denied" when using `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES | SYNCHRONIZE | FILE_TRAVERSE` - using `0` fixes it for me.

Comment: Github link is 404.

Comment: @JEvans it's fixed